# Why does function gives different values with the same input vector in R?

Tags: r

Here is the function:

```
mu <- 0
n <- 100
lambda <- c()
data <- c()
lb <- c()
ub <- c()
b <- function(n, lambda, mu, data, mu0) {
  data <- rnorm(n)
  f <- function(data, lambda, mu) {
    sum((data - mu) / (1 + lambda * (data - mu)))
  }
  f <- Vectorize(f, vectorize.args = c("lambda"))

  lb <- (1 - 1 / n) / (mu - max(data))
  ub <- (1 - 1 / n) / (mu - min(data))
  lambda <- unlist(uniroot(f, interval = c(lb, ub), data = data, mu = mu)[1])
  lambda * mu0
}
b <- Vectorize(b, vectorize.args = c("mu0"))
```

`mu0` is a vector, and I'd like the function to be evaluated at each component of this vector. But I noticed that lambda is changed for each component of mu0. For example, I put test vector `mu0 = (1,1,1,..)`: `b(mu0 = rep(1, 20), mu =mu, n = n)` and it evaluates the function at each vector component with different lambda values. The output:

```
root        root        root        root        root        root 
 0.10032298 -0.06997029  0.07912996 -0.01988526 -0.01656014  0.06468388
```

Why it is so?

Comment: Isn't `f` dependend on `data` which depends on `rnorm`?

Comment: Are you asking why a function of a random variable varies randomly?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

`rnorm` generates *random* numbers, and any subsequent call will generate a new set of numbers. In your function `b`, each call will use a new set of numbers as input to `f`.

Try this:

```
set.seed(1981) ## any magic number of your liking
b(mu0 = rep(1, 20), mu =mu, n = n)
set.seed(1981) ## repeat your magic number
b(mu0 = rep(1, 20), mu =mu, n = n)
```

The two calls should produce the same numbers. `set.seed` basically resets the random number generator.